Why does this fiber product diagram commute?
In the answer to this question: Graph Morphism Closed Immersion
They write this diagram, which they assume to be commutative.
$$
\require{AMScd}
\begin{CD}
X @>{\Gamma_f}>> X \times_S Y \\
@V{f}VV @V{f \times Y}VV \\
Y @>{\smash{\Delta_Y}}>> Y \times_S Y
\end{CD}
$$
However, it is not clear to me why it should be commutative a priori.

Both composites are maps $X \to Y \times_S Y$, which are determined via the universal property by a pair of maps $X \to Y$. Now check that in both cases this pair of maps is $(f, f)$.

Thanks man, I'm going to type it up and post it

This is an answer to the question, not just a comment. Please notice that comments should only be used to clarify, not answer the question. See How do comments work for more information. Therefore, I suggest to post your answer as an answer. This brings extra visibility to the answer und puts the question off the unanswered list. @QiaochuYuan

@Martin: the moderators have already threatened to suspend my account for the "crime" of answering questions that don't meet the community's "quality standards" (with which I do not agree). I don't want to deal with figuring out which questions meet these standards or not, so writing hints in comments is my compromise. If someone is going to suspend me for writing comments too, then... well, I don't have to be here. Frankly I think all of these rules are completely ridiculous.

I am sorry to hear that. Your account being suspended would be a tremendous loss to this community. Either way low-quality questions should neither be answered in the comments nor in form of answers. And this rule is useful for the community as a whole since it prevents users from abusing this site as their homework machine. You might dislike it, but when using a site its guidelines need to be respected. So with respect to quality of a question there is no difference in this rule of not posting answers in the comment section.

This rule is useful for many reasons. For example, your decision to post the answer in a comment means the solution cannot be found by search engines, and it leaves the question unanswered in list and search result pages, which is bad because it means the questions that actually still require an answer get mixed with already answered questions and hence become less visible and less easy to find. Also it cannot be marked as a duplicate when someone else asks the same.

Personally I also like to skip easy questions that have already been answered, but these days I always have to go to the comment section to check if it maybe has an answer even though it didn't appear to have one in the list page. Well there are many more reasons, all explained on meta. You also see from the upvotes that your "comment" (it is not a comment) is useful for others. It should have been an answer in the first place in my opinion. Every comment not asking for clarification or improvement is not aligning with the site guidelines.

The site guidelines are not there randomly, they have developed over time and in the end will benefit all users of this site. I also didn't always agree to them but I have changed my mind over time. Cheers.

I just want to clarify, I'm not using this site for homework, but to clarify concepts I saw in class. I genuinely spent an hour and a half trying to understand this before deciding to post to stackexchange because I felt like I was not getting anywhere. Unfortunately some people like myself aren't naturally talented at math

(Expanding Qiaochu's comment) As promised here's the solution. essentially it boils down to checking universal properties. Here are two relevant diagrams:


The first diagram expands the "top right direction" $(f, id_Y) \circ \Gamma_f$ while the second diagram expands the "bottom left direction" $\Delta_Y \circ f$. In both diagrams, we see that there are two maps from $X \to Y$ (in the first diagram, they are $f \circ id_X = f$ and $f$, and in the second diagram they are $f$ and $f$). Furthermore we see that they commute over $S$. Hence in both cases, we have an induced arrow $X \to Y \times_S Y$, and this arrow is unique by universal properties. Hence the two arrows $\Delta_Y \circ f$ and $(f, id_Y) \circ \Gamma_f$ are equal.
